# As soon as I touch a new file, my ls command with grep stops working

Tags: shell, grep, wildcards

I'm trying to find all the files in my home directory with a specific extension. If I only have one instance of the file extension, the ls command works perfectly fine, but as soon as I touch a new file with the same extension the ls command returns nothing.

I'm really not sure what's going on, and if someone could help point me to the right direction, that would be great.

[image]

Comment: The unquoted `*.java` expands to `hello2.java`, and there is no such file in `/home/gabriel/`. You don't even need grep here - just `ls /home/gabriel/*.java`

Comment: It also isn't best practice to pause the output of `ls`.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', both globs in `ls /home/gabriel/* | grep *.java`. And yes, the file has to exist in `Desktop/`. But of course `/home/gabriel/*` matches `/home/gabriel/Desktop`, and `ls` prints the contents of that, so the file only needs to exist in `Desktop/`, not also their home (as I mistakenly implied before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always quote your regex in single quotes, because the shell expand the wildcard to files.

So:

```
ls -1 | grep '\.java$'
```

Removed the wild card that is not necessary.

But parsing `ls` output is not a good idea, I would recommend `find`:

```
find . -name '*.java'
```

to search recursively, or

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*.java'
```

Or with GNU `find` or compatible:

```
find . -name '*.java' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
```

to search only the current directory.

In this particular case, since the only file at depth 0 is `.` (the current working directory where we instruct `find` to start looking for files)  which doesn't match the `*.java` pattern, you can get aways with omitting the `-mindepth 1`.